# What determines whether constructor or cast operator is called?

Tags: c++

When I use the following code, priority is given first to the constructor, rather than the cast operator. Is there any priority that defines which will be called first?

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class C1;
 class C2
 {
      int x;
 public:
     operator C2()
     {
       C2 temp;
       cout<<"operator function called"<<endl;
       return temp;
    }
 };
class C1
{
   int x;
public:
   C1():x(10){}
   C1(C2)
  {
    cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;
  }
};
 int main()
{
  C1 obj1;
  C2 obj2;
  obj1=obj2;
}
```

Output:

> constructor called

Comment: Talk about an X/Y question. Why do you think that passing a `C2` to some method of `C1` that takes a `C2` would require casting that `C2` to a copy of itself..?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but it's a **conversion** operator, not a **cast** operator. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. This conversion operator can be called without a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for the compiler to call `C2::operator C2()` since a `C2` object is already of type `C2`.

Whenever a copy is needed the compiler invokes the copy constructor `X(X const&)` or the move constructor `X(X&&)`, never `X::operator X()`.

Conversion operator and converting constructor are only used when the type of the argument does not match that of the parameter used to initialise the argument. See [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) for more details.

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed that the compiler doesn't warn of `C2::operator C2`. There is no situation it can be called, is there? Edit: apparently `obj2.operator C2()` is well formed.

Comment: @user2079303 Cannot think of a case when `C2::operator C2` would be called, apart from manual `obj2.operator C2()`.